# How to separate Sinhala letters from Sinhala words using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

EX:-
Input Word = "නමුත්"
Expected output = ['න','මු','ත්']

Comment: `ex = "නමුත්"` `print(list(ex))`

Comment: What have you tried/ researched so far?

Comment: You want to separate *letters* from *words*? How does that work? Aren't words *made* from letters?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - `list(ex)` produces `['න', 'ම', 'ු', 'ත', '්']` so double byte characters are involved here

Comment: @Sayse You're probably right, but I'll wait for clarification from OP before I post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with regex pattern `\w\W?` to find all the letters:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'\w\W?', "නමුත්"))
```

This outputs:

```
['න', 'මු', 'ත්']
```

Comment: Indeed. Fixed then. Thanks.